# AJAX chat, setInterval stacks id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

I'm doing a chat at school using AJAX. If you click on a link (the person you want to chat with), there's a onclick='load(id)' where the persons id is inside. And that works fine for one person, but when you click on another person it's like the id's stack up. So i figured out that the interval is not cleared, but after hours of searching i still can't find anything that helps me! So i hope you guys can help me. I'm a completely newbie with AJAX..

Frontend:

```
<li><a onclick='load( ID )'> USERNAME </a></li>
```

AJAX:

```
function load(id) {
            /*remove old interval?*/
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                console.log(id);
                //update chatbox
                $(".content-box").load("config.php", {
                    "id" : id
                }, function() {
                    //loading config.php
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Btw according to my teacher i need a 'handler' and/or need to write this more oop. But as i wrote, this is completely new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself..

I made a little test-site first, so the markup isn't quite the same. But in the end it wont matter.
Frontend:

```
<button onclick='obj.clear(), obj.setId(1), obj.interval()'>
        click me
    </button>
    <button onclick='obj.clear(), obj.setId(2), obj.interval()'>
        click me
    </button>
    <button onclick='obj.clear(), obj.setId(3), obj.interval()'>
        click me
    </button>
```

Backend:

```
var obj = {
            id : 0,
            setId : function(id){
                this.id = id;
            },
            interval : function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    console.log(obj.id);
                    //update chatbox
                    $(".content-box").load("testing.php", {

                    }, function() {
                        //load config.php

                    });
                }, 1000);
            },
            clear : function() {
                clearInterval(obj.id);
            }
        }
```

Thanks to the people who tried to help me on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(id) {
            /*remove old interval?*/
            var interval = setInterval(function() 
            {
                $.ajax({
                url: 'config.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {"id":id },
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(result) 
                {
                 var hasclass = $(".content-box").hasClass("chat_"+id);
                 if(hasclass == false)
                 {
                  var create_div = "<div class='chat_"+id+"'></div>";
                  $(".content-box").append(create_div);
                 }
                 $(".chat_"+id).html(result);
                  
                }
            });

            }, 1000);
        }

</script>
```

```html
<div class="content-box"></div>

<ul>
<li><a onclick='load(1)'> Ashish </a></li>
<li><a onclick='load(7)'> Akash </a></li>
</ul>
Here pass your id in function load().
```

Comment: This does not work for me i'm sorry.. The interval still isnt cleared and the id's keep comming in every second (just more and more for each time i push a student..)

Answer (score 0):

An event handler is the way to go here - the click on the links is the event.

You would also need the ID of each specific student, so put those in the link as data and then use those inside the event handler - put the interval id in the :"wrapper" element of the list so we know where it is and can use it.

revised markup for clarity

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li><a class="student" data-studentid="2">USERNAME</a></li>
  <li><a class="student" data-studentid="3">Harvy</a></li>
  <li><a class="student" data-studentid="4">Wally</a></li>
</ul>
```

code for the handler

```
$('#mylist').on('click', '.student', function(event) {
  // stop the default link (a) action
  event.preventDefault();
  //get prior id
  var priorStudentIntervalID = $('#mylist').data('priorinterval');
  if (priorStudentIntervalID) {
    //intervalID is a unique interval ID you can pass to clearInterval().
    window.clearInterval(priorStudentIntervalID);
  }
  // get the id from the a element that was clicked
  var studentID = $(this).data('studentid');
  var newinterval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(studentID);
    //update chatbox
    $(".content-box").load("config.php", {
      "id": studentID 
    }, function() {
      //loading config.php
    });
  }, 1000);
  //push in the new interval id
  $('#mylist').data('priorinterval', newinterval);
});
```

Note that here we bind to the UL and use that to hold the prior interval id.

Basically, you then get a refresh every 1000 milliseconds on a given student until the next click

Comment: Note that the IMPORTANT thing here is that ONLY ONE student is being "refreshed" at a given time - so we clear the prior interval.

Comment: Note that i COULD have put the interval in a global ID variable - but I do not like global variables (yours is not global, it is inside your function and gets a new one for every student

Comment: When i run the code the console says: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: priorStudentInterval is not defined'.. :(

Comment: Yep I had a syntax error in the conditional and used priorStudentInterval not priorStudentIntervalID  sorry, updated the post;  Note that you should always take efforts to totally understand any code you find prior to using it; that is one benefit of sites like this one; learning stuff you do not know.